# Error inflating class com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PaymentButtonContainer

Tags: android, android-layout, paypal

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.payment.PaymentPayPal">

    <com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PaymentButtonContainer
        android:id="@+id/paymentButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity class:

```
class PaymentPayPal : BaseActivity() {

    private val YOUR_CLIENT_ID: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_pay_pal)
    }
}
```

also tried binding nothing happens

build.gradle(app)

1. minSdk=21
2. dependencies {
   implementation 'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.8.1'
   }

Error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.voterswik/com.voterswik.ui.payment.PaymentPayPal}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.voterswik:layout/activity_payment_pay_pal: Binary XML file line #9 in com.voterswik:layout/activity_payment_pay_pal: Error inflating class com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PaymentButtonContainer

Comment: If the sdk is properly imported, you can try `Invalidate Cache & Restart` in Android Studio or contact PayPal's dev team/forum if issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this error is due to non-reachable class PaymentButtonContainer

This is because it should build a config before its use, so go to paypal docs
https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/paypal-mobile-checkout/android/

and check whether implemented correctly, is you "**implement configuration on a subclass of Application()**"  which will call at very start of project. To set the configuration

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use constraints in a LinearLayout.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

If you remove that line you will be able to run your app.

Comment: No, that's not work as well actually i used constraint layout before linear so that's why i forgot to remove but still prob is same.

Answer (score 0):

You may try these steps.

1. make sure you have the latest implementation

e.g. implementation'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.8.8'

2. make your PayPalCheckout.setConfig in the MainActivity
3. Create a new Activity and put the PaymentButtonContainer on the new activity.xml